# KOA2+node+ejs Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

Use kOA2 + node js + ajax to grab the web page data and display the result information on the front page:

query.js

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const charset = require('superagent-charset');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

charset(superagent);

function Rate(from, to, queryNumber) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.queryNumber = queryNumber;
}

module.exports = Rate;

Rate.query = function query(rate, callback) {
    let URL = 'http://qq.ip138.com/hl.asp?from=' + rate.from + '&to=' + rate.to + '&q=' + rate.queryNumber;
    superagent.get(URL)
       .charset('gbk')
       .end((err, sres)=> {
          if (err) {
              return next(err);
          }
          var $ = cheerio.load(sres.text);
          var queryResult = [];
          queryResult[0] = $(".rate td").eq(4).text();
          queryResult[1] = $(".rate td").eq(5).text();
          callback(null, queryResult);

       })
};
```

---

index.js

```
const index = require('koa-router')();
const Rate = require('../models/query');

index.get('/s*', async (ctx, next) => {
    let rate = new Rate(ctx.query.from, ctx.query.to, ctx.query.queryNumber);
    await Rate.query(rate, (err, queryResult) => {
      if (err) {
         return next(err);
      } else {
         return ctx.render('query', {
                   title: '查询结果',
                   rate: queryResult[0],
                   amount: queryResult[1]
      });
      return next();
      }

    });
```

when visit “/s*” page, appear：(Node: 808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled hate rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can not set headers after they are sent. Error, and the page can not jump.

Tried a lot of ways, but still do not know where to return in advance.

Is now known, because after the end of ctx, but also to call render to write data. The The But that is not where to change. Pls Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update

```
const index = require('koa-router')();
const Rate = require('../models/query');

index.get('/s*', async (ctx, next) => {
    let rate = new Rate(ctx.query.from, ctx.query.to, ctx.query.queryNumber);
    await Rate.query(rate, (err, queryResult) => {
      if (err) {
         return next(err);
      } else {
         return ctx.render('query', {
                   title: '查询结果',
                   rate: queryResult[0],
                   amount: queryResult[1]
      });
      return next();
      }

    });
```

to

```
const index = require('koa-router')();
const Rate = require('../models/query');

index.get('/s*', async (ctx, next) => {
    let rate = new Rate(ctx.query.from, ctx.query.to, ctx.query.queryNumber);
    await Rate.query(rate, (err, queryResult) => {
      if (err) {
         return next(err);
      } else {
         return ctx.render('query', {
                   title: '查询结果',
                   rate: queryResult[0],
                   amount: queryResult[1]
      });
      }

    });
```

Comment: Changed to your code, but it also will the same problem.